# How do we know that non-hechshered food is not kilayim or kilay hakerem?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, chutz-laaretz, agriculture, kilayim-forbidden-mixture

"Kilayim" and "kilay hakerem" are two classes of prohibitions on eating from "mixed" fields (in which more than one type of crop is planted.) "Kilayim," as I understand it, specifically refers to the prohibition on wheat and barley grown together, whereas "Kilay Hakerem" refers to a prohibition on "eating from a vineyard with other seeds mixed into it."

According to the Mishna (Kidushin ch.1, #9), these laws are not actually restricted to the land of Israel, but must be observed worldwide, since they are halacha l'Moshe mi-Sinai.

So how do we know that fruit, vegetables, wheat, barley etc. that are sold commercially outside of Israel (without a hechsher) follow these laws? If not, why are we allowed to eat from them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rambam writes ([Maachalos Asuros 10:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=5&hilchos=28&perek=10&halocha=11)-12):

> ספק ערלה וכלאי הכרם בארץ ישראל אסור. בסוריא והיא ארצות שכבש דוד מותר.
>   כיצד היה כרם וערלה וענבים נמכרות חוצה לו. היה ירק זרוע בתוכו וירק נמכר
>   חוצה לו. שמא ממנו הוא זה שמא מאחר. בסוריא מותר ובחוצה לארץ אפילו ראה
>   הענבים יוצאות מכרם ערלה או ירק יוצא מן הכרם לוקח מהן. והוא שלא יראה
>   אותו בוצר מן הערלה או לוקט הירק בידו
>
> Doubtful [*orlah*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlah) or *k'laei hakerem* in the Land of Israel is
>   forbidden. In [Suryah](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90) (which is the land that David conquered) it
>   is permitted. What is a case of doubt? If there was a vineyard of
>   *orlah*, and grapes were being sold next to the vineyard, or (for *kilayim*) there were vegetables being sold next to a vineyard, and one is uncertain if they came from this field or from another. In
>   Suryah, it is permitted; outside of the Land, even if one saw the
>   grapes coming out of an *orlah* field, or vegetables coming out of a
>   vineyard, it is permitted, so long as he didn't see those things being
>   harvested.
>
> כרם שהוא ספק ערלה או ספק כלאים בארץ ישראל אסור ובסוריא מותר ואין צריך
>   לומר בחוצה לארץ
>
> A vineyard that is doubtfully *orlah* or *k'laei hakerem* is forbidden
>   in the Land of Israel, permitted in Suryah, and obviously also
>   permitted outside of the Land.

(*free translation*)